# Can I change the commands certain buttons activate on my dell WM514 mouse?

Tags: mouse

I can open synapse by using the right/left bumper(is that what you call it?)+drag left. Are there certain files to edit, or do I have to download certain software?

Answer (score 0):

Config-options by editing files: I found none. The right/left bumper works as Ctrl-key with the wheel to zoom in/out. 
In ["Windows 8"](http://www.7tutorials.com/introducing-windows-8-what-are-charms/) Win+C activates charms. Push a right/left bumper and move slowly gives the same response as push Win+C.

Xfce: If I touch one (or two) bumpers and move slowly to the left (left-hand mouse), I get my (Gnome)calculator. It is the response of the WM514 to the Super+C-key.

Unity: If you touch one ore two bumpers and move slowly to the left (left-hand mouse), you get photo search (=default Super+C).

You can edit the generic Super+C-config for your system and maybe change it to another application (like filebrowser, I tested Thunar - it works).